# Merging nested defaultdicts

Tags: python, data-structures, union, defaultdict

I have this:

```
dict1 = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))
dict1['rl1']['sh1'] = ['a','b']
dict1['rl1']['sh2'] = ['c','d']
dict1['rl2']['sh1'] = ['c','d']

dict2 = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))
dict2['rl1']['sh1'] = ['p','q']
dict2['rl1']['sh3'] = ['r','s']
dict2['rl3']['sh1'] = ['r','s']
```

I want to do a union of the two defaultdicts, this would be the result:

```
uniondict = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))
uniondict['rl1']['sh1'] = ['a','b','p','q']
uniondict['rl1']['sh2'] = ['c','d']
uniondict['rl1']['sh3'] = ['r','s']
uniondict['rl2']['sh1'] = ['c','d']
uniondict['rl3']['sh1'] = ['r','s']
```

I'm not sure on how obtain this result.. I've tried using dict1.items() and dict2.items(), or update function, but i must be missing something because i can't manage to get the "union" of the defaultdicts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

slightly more 'elegant':

```
uniondict = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))
for k1, v1 in dict1.items() + dict2.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        uniondict[k1][k2] += v2
```

for a more memory-efficient solution:

```
from itertools import chain
uniondict = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))
for k1, v1 in chain(dict1.iteritems(), dict2.iteritems()):
    for k2, v2 in v1.iteritems():
        uniondict[k1][k2] += v2
```

this will use iterators to prevent creating temporary lists in memory

[itertools.chain docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

---

for posterity, here is a generic function that will merge nested dictionary objects (defaultdict or no) where the second-tier value supports the `+` operator. (lists, ints, sets, etc):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

def merge_nested_dicts(dict_list):
    uniondict = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))
    for k1, v1 in chain(*[d.iteritems() for d in dict_list]):
        for k2, v2 in v1.iteritems():
            uniondict[k1][k2] += v2
    return uniondict
```

Comment: thanks but i defined it like this actually:
def uniondicts(listDicts):
    for dic in listDicts:
        for k,v [....]
Works perfectly! Since my dicts are not that big i'm not sure the memory efficient solution is really indispensable

Answer (score 4):

```
dict12 = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))
for k,v in dict1.items():
    for k1,v1 in v.items():
        dict12[k][k1] = v1
for k,v in dict2.items():
    for k2,v2 in v.items():
        dict12[k][k2] += v2
for k,v in dict12.items():
    for k12,v12 in v.items():
        print "dict12[%r][%r] = %r" % (k,k12,v12)
```

Comment: that's what I was supposing... Dunno why I was looking for a more "elegant" way of dealing with this...